# Why does an exe called in Excel VBA not output a file?

Tags: c++, vba, file-io, excel

So I have a Macro-enabled Excel/VBA Workbook with a button which writes a .txt file and then calls a .exe in the same directory.  The .exe is written in C++ and is ***supposed*** to output another file.

The problem I'm having is that for some reason when the Excel Workbook calls the C++ .exe, the executable processes the information from the .txt just fine, but the output file doesn't ever show up. But, if I have the workbook simply make the .txt file, and then I execute the C++ program myself then the program outputs the file correctly.

It seems that calling the .exe from the Excel/VBA workbook is causing the .exe not to output a file.

Here is the Excel/VBA code

```
Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\excel.txt") For Output As #1
Print #1, MyString
Close #1
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyProgram.exe"), 
NewWindow:=True
```

And the C++ is split among multiple files but the key part which may be causing issue is below

```
ofstream OutputFile;
int Sequence[12];
...
...
OutputFile.open("Output.solution");
for (int i=1;i<12;i++)
    OutputFile << Int_to_String(Sequence[i]) << " ";
OutputFile.close();
```

So how can I get the C++ executable to output the "Output.solution" file when being called from Excel VBA? Just to be clear - if I run the C++ program separately it **does** output the file.

Edit: When executing the .exe separately, the proper information is put into the "Output.solution" file in the same directory, but when calling from Excel/VBA, the .exe instead places an **empty** "Output.solution" into the My Documents folder.

How can I make this file appear back in the original directory when calling from Excel/VBA? and how can I ensure it will actually fill the file with information as it does when called outside excel?

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* that your current directory is what you think it is?

It may be that it's somewhere other than your workbook path in which case the output files will be created there rather than where you expect.

Easiest way to check this is to execute the C++ program without the path:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("MyProgram.exe"), NewWindow:=True
```

and see if it complains bitterly about not finding the executable.

Another way is to use a known location (temporarily) for the output file:

```
OutputFile.open("c:\\knowndir\\Output.solution");
```

and check that it's created. If it is, then there's nothing wrong with your executable, you're just in a directory different to what you think.

Also, search your entire disk for the `Output.solution` file. If you're in a different directory *that's* where the file will be created.

If it turns out that is the problem, probably the easiest solution is to change the directory before running the executable. VBA has a [`chdir` command](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/chdir.php) for just this purpose. You may need to change it back afterwards depending on your needs and you can use `curdir` for this.

Comment: Yes I am positive, because when I run the C++ program separately, the file does show up in that same directory & every part of the c++ runs smoothly. But when I run it from the excel/vba then the program runs on the command prompt window showing the correct command prompt output, but doesn't make a file.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far. I deleted the old .solution file and reran the excel call and searched for the .solution. It turns out that for some reason when Excel is calling the exe, the output file is being created in the "My Documents" folder. Do you happen to know how I could change this to the current directory without using the absolute location (because I want this program/system to be portable)?

Comment: @user2016670, use Excel's `chdir` command _before_ running the executable. That would be my first try.

Comment: After playing with it for a couple of hours, I found that it was an embarrassingly simple solution:

Add "ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path" before calling the executable. This made the C++ executable's output file show up in the current directory as it should, and allowed it to properly populate with data.

Comment: Ha yeah I just now read your latest comment after posting my last one. Thanks for the help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a tool like SysInternal's Process Monitor to see if the file write is occurring at all, and if not, why not.

My guess is that you're probably falling foul of the executable running in a different directory to the directory you expect it to run from. Try outputting to an absolute location (or calling SetCurrentDirectory first) to see if this helps.